# Fingerprint scanner not detected when using Android 6.0 Fingerprint API on Samsung S5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Androids 6.0 Fingerprint API cannot detect my fingerprint scanner on Samsung S5.

- Screen lock is secured with fingerprints
- I've 2 Fingerprints registered in fingerprint manager
- My S5 is updated to android 6.0
- The fingerprint scanner is working fine, I use it to unlock my phone
- I cannot find anything to do with fingerprints in the Security Settings (Was told to allow Apps to have access to fingerprint here, but its not on it)

In App Info of each app, is says Permissions: No Permissions Requested however in each of the sample app's ive tried it meantions they do request permission...However I haven't seen the request pop up

I've tried the google fingerprint scanner authentication [Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) and I've also tried [this app](https://github.com/JessicaThornsby/FingerprintAuthentication)

Any idea's on what could to be the problem?

Comment: If anyone is interested...It works on an Ulefone Power android phone...

Answer (score 0):

You are using  FingerPrint API of Android which is not supported by Samsung Device.You have to use there SDK for FingerPrint Authentication which is Pass SDK.Check this [link of Pass SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass).

In the AndroidManifest.xml File.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ah. I see. Is Samsung the only manufacturer that has their own API? Every other brand is safe, right?

Comment: @UnknownDistance yes as per my knowledge fingerPrint API works with other device

Comment: I m facing same problem with VIVO YS55. Can you give me a solution for this issue on this particular brand?